# Store MySQL results in PHP array for two queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How do I create, store and output an array that uses two different mysql queries?

I tried to make a simple example.

```
$select1 = "SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries ...";
while ($select1) {
   ...store country results in array...

  $select2 = "SELECT city_id, city_name FROM cities where '" . $select1['country_id'] . "'..."); // depends on select1
  while ($select2) {
    ...store city results in array...
  }

}

**output something like this:**

country_id = 1
country_name = United States

  city_id = 1
  city_name = New York

  city_id = 2
  city_name = Las Vegas

country_id = 2
country_name = Canada

  city_id = 3
  city_name = Ottawa
```

Comment: You want to get all cities of all countries right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if you are checking for errors, preparing or escaping your queries but please do so.

To generate your array you can do it with this:

```
    $list = [];
    $countries = $link->query("SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries ...");

    while ($country_row /*fetch from $countries*/) {

        $country_id = $country_row['country_id']; 

        $country_info = [
                'country_id' => $country_id,
                'country_name' => $country_row['country_name'],
                'country_cities' => []
         ];

        $cities_stmt = "SELECT city_id, city_name FROM cities where $country_id...";
        $cities = $link->query($cities_stmt);

        while ($city_row /*fetch from $cities*/) {

            $city_id = $city_row['city_id'];

            $country_info['country_cities'][$city_id] = [
                    'city_id' => $city_id,
                    'city_name' => $city_row['city_name']
            ];
        }

        $list[$country_id] = $country_info;
    }
```

To display your array you can do:

```
    foreach ( $list as $country_id => $country_info ) {

        echo "Country ID: $country_id<br />";
        echo 'Country Name: ' . $country_info['country_name'] . '<br />';
        echo 'Country Cities:<br />';

        $cities = $country_info['country_cities']; 

        foreach ( $cities as $city_id => $city_info ) {

                echo "   City ID: $city_id<br />";
                echo '   City Name: ' . $city_info['city_name'] . '<br />';
        }

        echo '<br />';
    }
```

Also, if you know the country id or city id you can do:

```
    echo 'City Name: ' . $list[$country_id]['country_cities'][$city_id]['city_name'] . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your country_id as the key for your array.. So basically,

```
$select1 = mysqli_query("SELECT country_id, country_name FROM countries");
while ($country_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $array[$country_id]['country_id'] = $country_row ['country_id'];
   $array[$country_id]['country'] = $country_row['country_name'];

  $select2 = mysqli_query("SELECT city_id, city_name FROM cities where '" . $select1['country_id'] ."' "); // depends on select1
  while ($city_row = mysqli_fetch_array($select2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $array[$country_id]['cities'][]['city_id'] = $city_row['city_id'];
   $array[$country_id]['cities'][]['city_name'] = $city_row['city_name']
  }
}
```

In order to print these back out using foreach (as you asked in comments), you must loop through both levels of the array

```
foreach($array as $country){
   //Loop through the countries that we queried and stored 
   echo 'Country Name: '.$country['country_name'].'<br/>';
   echo 'Country ID: '.$country['country_id'].'<br/>';
   echo 'Cities in country: <br/>';
   //Loop through the cities within this country
   foreach($country['cities'] as $city){
      echo 'City ID: '.$city['city_id'].'<br/>';
      echo 'City Name: '.$city['city_name'].'<br/>';
   }

}
```

Comment: And how do I output the array with foreach()?

Comment: `foreach($arr as $a){
     $a['country']; //Country
     $a['country_id']; //Country id
     foreach($a['cities'] as $city){
         
     }
}`

Comment: If you are in a hurry, why did you answer? Your answer is not very helpful unless you already know the basics. And if you know the basics you won't ask this question. So this won't help anyone. It will only annoy anyone seeking the same answer as I do.

Comment: I was heading into a meeting. I will update my answer to further elaborate, but in a comment I cannot exactly give a lot of details.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the output of one query and mailmerging it into another query in a nested loop is an anti-pattern. Use a join:

```
select country_ID, country_name,
  City_Id, city_name
From countries cn
Inner join cities ct
On CT.country_id = cn.country_ID
```

Then....

```
$cities=array();
$country_names=array();

While($r=mysqli_fetch_array($handle)) {
     $country_names[$r['country_id']]=$r['country_name'];
     If (!is_array($cities[$r['country_id'])) $cities[$r['country_id']]=array();
     $cities[$r['country_id']][$r['city_id']]=$r['city_name'];
}
```