# I need to nest 2 arrays so that I can echo order header as well as order item details

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, pdo

I have updated my original post based on what I learned from your comments below. It is a much simpler process than I originally thought.

```
    require '../database.php';

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE id = 430";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($id));
            $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo    'Order Num: ' . $data['id'] . '<br>';

    $sql = "SELECT  * FROM Order_items 
            JOIN    Parts ON Parts.id = Order_Items.part_id 
            WHERE   Order_Items.orders_id = 430";

            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($line_item_id));
            $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            while ($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                echo '- ' . $data['part_num'] . $data['qty'] . "<br>";
            }

     Database::disconnect();
```

Unfortunately, only my first query is producing results. The second query is producing the following ERROR LOG: "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Order_items' doesn't exist" but I am expecting the following results.

Expected Results from Query 1: 
     Order Num: 430

Expected Results from Query 2:

```
- Screws 400
- Plates 35
- Clips 37
- Poles 7
- Zip ties 45
```

Comment: Why 2 queries? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312038/store-mysql-results-in-php-array-for-two-queries/36318001#36318001

Comment: so maybe one query will do it but 2 different $result arrays, or a nested $result array?

Comment: The Order_Items table has 117 part_num, so I need an array for that. The Orders (header) just has one corresponding record with header columns. I could use one query, but I don't want to repeat the header details 117 times. I want to show header at the top and part_num/qty at the bottom

Comment: Two queries are fine, usually an order has one header and multiple lines.
Leaving alone the question why two different DB access styles are used, I'd like to understand your problem better. Why nested arrays? Just run the query on the table **Orders**, display the results, and run the query for **Order_Items** with the same order ID and display the results in a *while* loop. Where is the problem?

Comment: @StanWiniecki - good question. I know how to query and echo the header details. That was the easy part. Someone showed me how to do an array using mysqli_query. Now I have two different solutions. I tried two separate queries and displays. I will try it again.

Comment: But PDO outputs results also in an array... Don't be intimidated by the name :) Your first array is called $data, and the other is called $row. These are "associative arrays", so instead of indexing by number, like: $array[0], $array[1] etc, you have an array indexed by field names from the query, hence $data['address'] or $row['qty'] contain the data from a respective field in a record/row fetched by a query. Each fetch from the query results in an array containing all values of all fields in a subsequent record. If you want, we can move to chat, as comments are not really designed for this.

Comment: Thanks. Found chat

Comment: I think chat requires a reputation of 20 minimum. I'll write an answer summarizing stuff.

Comment: @BrickShy: no you don't need 2 queries, you don't need 2 arrays. You don't seperate reading the data from writing output. You iterate through the results of a single query. At the start of the first iteration you output the header. After the last iteration you output the footer. Alternatively do the header and footer in the same iteration and move them around with css.

Comment: What is unclear about error you get?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Thank you for that comment. You guys are good! Really. You made me think and look closely and see that I had a slightly incorrect name. It works! Thank you all for making me think and for teaching!! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand where you are coming from, let's explain a couple of things.

1.PDO and mysqli are two ways of accessing the database; they essentially do the same things, but the notation is different.

2.Arrays are variables with multiple "compartments". Most typical array has the compartments identified by a numerical index, like:

```
$array[0] = 'OR12345'; //order number
$array[1] = '2017-03-15'; //order date
$array[2] = 23; //id of a person/customer placing the order
```

etc. But this would require us to remember which number index means what. So in PHP there are *associative arrays*, which allow using text strings as indexes, and are used for fetching SQL query results.

3.The statement

```
$data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

or

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

do exactly the same thing: put a record (row) from a query into an array, using field names as indexes. This way it's easy to use the data, because you can use field names (with a little bit around them) for displaying or manipulating the field values.

4.The

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

does two things. It checks if there **is** a row still to fetch from the query results. and while there is one - it puts it into the array $row for you to use, and repeats (all the stuff between { and }).

So you fetch the row, display the results in whatever form you want, and then loop to fetch another row. If there are no more rows to fetch - the loop ends.

5.You should avoid using commas in the FROM clause in a query. This notation can be used only if the fields joining the tables are obvious (named the same), but it is bad practice anyway. The joins between tables should be specified explicitly. In the first query you want the header only, and there is no additional table needed in your example, so you should have just

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE Orders.Order_ID = 12345
```

whereas in the second query I understand you have a table Parts, which contains descriptions of various parts that can be ordered? If so, then the second query should have:

```
SELECT *
FROM Order_items
JOIN Parts ON Parts.ID = Order_Items.Part_ID
WHEERE Order_Items.Order_ID = 12345
```

If in your Orders table you had a field for the ID of the supplier *Supplier_ID*, pointing to a Suppliers table, and an ID of the person placing the order *Customer_ID*, pointing to a Customers table, then the first query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders
JOIN Suppliers ON Suppliers.ID = Orders.Supplier_ID
JOIN Customers ON Customers.ID = Orders.Customer_ID
WHERE Orders.Order_ID = 12345
```

Hope this is enough for you to learn further on your own :).

Comment: Thank you, Stan, for the guidance. It is much simpler thought process now. I can only get one of my queries to work, but it feels better. The only place I could include my updated question was to put it up top in the original question.

Comment: @Tim Sideris : I see you decided to change both queries to PDO. I would probably go for changing the first one to mysqli, but that's because I'm more familiar with it.  In the second query you retrieve the first record with the line 
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
then do nothing with it and start a *while* loop - this way you lose the first record provided by the query! Remove the first one and just leave the one within the *while* loop. Also, if helped, consider accepting my answer :)