# SQL Select producing slightly different results in phpAdmin vs. phpHTML

Tags: php, mysql, select

I consistently miss the first row result, which is more noticeable when there is only one row result.

I have a problem with my PDO commands. Any suggestions for how to correct please? If I remove the $pod->prepare nothing works. Not sure what to do?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM Order_Items 
        JOIN    Parts ON Parts.id = Order_Items.part_id
        WHERE   Order_Items.orders_id = $id
        AND     qty <> 0
        ORDER BY Parts.id";

        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array());
        $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Roy says this is not needed

        while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo    '<tr>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['part_num'] . '</td>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['part_desc'] . '</td>';
            echo    '<td>' . $row['qty'] . '</td>';
        }

    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating  `$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.
When you asing `$q to $row`, `$q->fetch` is cleared (with no data) so in the `IF sentence` you have no rows to fetch in $q. 
You have to remove `$row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and just use it in the IF.

Also try to do a **fetchAll()** to `$q`.

```
$result = $query -> fetchAll();

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    /*CODE*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!

Comment: I pointed the same thing out to you on March 29th in your other question. It's in the comment to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43080804/7726099  
It pays to read comments in full, would have saved you a day of head scratching ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting an SQL error. This has nothing to do with the value of the line_item_id database column.

You are getting a PHP error. The variable `$line_item_id` is undefined.

Comment: Since you haven't bound any parameters in the query, I'm at a loss as to why you're putting any variable there in the first place (or using `prepare` in the first place for that matter)